# Load external content before runApp

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter app that needs to loads external data for content that is used all across the app. I use a Provider to make the data available. But the content in this Provider should be fetched from a remote source. I've got it to work, but I'm not sure if this is the best 'Flutter' way to move forward.

I have a straight-forward Provider:

```
class Content extends ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, String> content;

  Future<dynamic> loadContent() async {
    // method simplified for Stack Overflow
    ContentRepository repo = new ContentRepository();
    Map<String, String> data = repo.fetchContent();
    content = data;
  }

  // other helper methods below
}
```

And this `loadContent` is trigger in `main`:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  // removed unrelated stuff
  Content applicationContent = Content();
  try {
    await applicationContent.loadContent();
  } catch (e) {
    // If we can not load the data, continue with the fallback content please
  }

  return runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      // other providers hidden
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => applicationContent,
      ),
    ],
    // ....
  ));
}
```

Although this works perfectly fine, I feel there is a better way to do this. Am I missing something?

Comment: why do you use `ChangeNotifierProvider`? if your `loadContent` returns a `Future` so use [FutureProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/FutureProvider-class.html)

Comment: Thanks @pskink! I was not aware of the `FutureProvider`. There might be another moment while using the app that the content will get updated, so therefore I figured the `ChangeNotifierProvider` was a good idea. Will take a look at that one, thanks.

Comment: sure, your welcome - [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/index.html) you have a table of existing providers (go to the very bottom of the page)